# ZXing on WP7 with preview - mark QR on screen?

Tags: windows-phone-7, zxing

I'm using ZXing per [this link](http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/qr-code-scanning-on-windows-phone-75-using-zxlib/)... It works great, but is it possible to get coordinates of QR on stream so I could overlay a rectangle indicating read QR on the rectangle that show camera feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you using this work by Stephanie Hertrich that contains a layer over the camera so you can put your own info.

[WP7 : Real-time video scan a barcode/QR code in your app using ZXing lib](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2011/11/07/wp7-real-time-video-scan-a-barcode-qr-code-in-your-app-using-zxing-lib.aspx)